# Why does my button stop working when it is placed too low on my view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

I have an app that works fine on a 4 inch iPhone. However, when I test the app on the 3.5 inch iPhone, my buttons near the bottom of the view don't work anymore. I have buttons higher up that are still working fine. I tested this out on the 4 inch simulator - when I put a button even closer to the bottom, it wouldn't work. By not working, I mean they are no longer clickable.

Is there something thats stopping me from operating too low on a view? I currently use a container view with a scroll view which points to my view controller.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some of the code that describes your view's set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell.
If you are working with Interface Builder, you can't even show us what's your setup. This doesn't help

My first guess is that you either have an invisible element on top of your buttons, or that something funny is happening with the content view of your scroll view.

Try to place your buttons directly in the parent/root view. If that works, bring them back to their original position in the view hierarchy, one level at a time. This should give you an idea of where they stop working, and what might be causing it.

Comment: Nice! So I moved my buttons to the actual container views and they started working. Although I'm still not sure of the problem, I'm assuming the container view for some reason was limiting the functionality. But dragging them to the container view makes them work.